# How search values < 0.5 and mask include word new?

Tags: prometheus

I have content

```
{"status":"success","data":{"resultType":"matrix","result":[{"metric":{"__name__":"process_status","process_id":"process_fly1","instance":"server01","job":"new_job1"},"values":[[1516627862,"1"],[1516627922,"1"],[1516627982,"1"],[1516628042,"1"],[1516628102,"1"],[1516628162,"1"],[1516628222,"1"],[1516628282,"1"],[1516628342,"1"],[1516628402,"1"],[1516628462,"1"],[1516628522,"1"],[1516628582,"1"],[1516628642,"1"],[1516628702,"1"],[1516628762,"1"],[1516628822,"1"],[1516628882,"1"],[1516628942,"1"],[1516629002,"1"],[1516629062,"1"],[1516629122,"1"],[1516629182,"1"],[1516629242,"1"],[1516629302,"1"],[1516629362,"1"],[1516629422,"1"],[1516629482,"1"],[1516629542,"1"],[1516629602,"1"],[1516629662,"1"],[1516629722,"1"],[1516629782,"1"],[1516629842,"1"],[1516629902,"1"],[1516629962,"1"],[1516630022,"1"],[1516630082,"1"],[1516630142,"1"],[1516630202,"1"],[1516630262,"1"],[1516630322,"1"],[1516630382,"1"],[1516630442,"1"],[1516630502,"1"],[1516630562,"1"],[1516630622,"1"],[1516630682,"1"],[1516630742,"1"],[1516630802,"1"],[1516630862,"1"],[1516630922,"1"],[1516630982,"1"],[1516631042,"1"],[1516631102,"1"],[1516631162,"1"],[1516631222,"1"],[1516631282,"1"],[1516631342,"1"],[1516631402,"1"],[1516631462,"1"]]},{"metric":{"__name__":"process_status","process_id":"process_grow","instance":"server01","job":"new_job1"},"values":[[1516627862,"0"],[1516627922,"0"],[1516627982,"0"],[1516628042,"0"],[1516628102,"0"],[1516628162,"0"],[1516628222,"0"],[1516628282,"0"],[1516628342,"0"],[1516628402,"0"],[1516628462,"0"],[1516628522,"0"],[1516628582,"0"],[1516628642,"0"],[1516628702,"0"],[1516628762,"0"],[1516628822,"0"],[1516628882,"0"],[1516628942,"0"],[1516629002,"0"],[1516629062,"0"],[1516629122,"0"],[1516629182,"0"],[1516629242,"0"],[1516629302,"0"],[1516629362,"0"],[1516629422,"0"],[1516629482,"0"],[1516629542,"0"],[1516629602,"0"],[1516629662,"0"],[1516629722,"0"],[1516629782,"0"],[1516629842,"0"],[1516629902,"0"],[1516629962,"0"],[1516630022,"0"],[1516630082,"0"],[1516630142,"0"],[1516630202,"0"],[1516630262,"0"],[1516630322,"0"],[1516630382,"0"],[1516630442,"0"],[1516630502,"0"],[1516630562,"0"],[1516630622,"0"],[1516630682,"0"],[1516630742,"0"],[1516630802,"0"],[1516630862,"0"],[1516630922,"0"],[1516630982,"0"],[1516631042,"0"],[1516631102,"0"],[1516631162,"0"],[1516631222,"0"],[1516631282,"0"],[1516631342,"0"],[1516631402,"0"],[1516631462,"0"]]},
{"metric":{"__name__":"process_status","process_id":"process_fly2","instance":"server01","job":"new_job1"},"values":[[1516627862,"1"],[1516627922,"1"],[1516627982,"1"],[1516628042,"1"],[1516628102,"1"],[1516628162,"1"],[1516628222,"1"],[1516628282,"1"],[1516628342,"1"],[1516628402,"1"],[1516628462,"1"],[1516628522,"1"],[1516628582,"1"],[1516628642,"1"],[1516628702,"1"],[1516628762,"1"],[1516628822,"1"],[1516628882,"1"],[1516628942,"1"],[1516629002,"1"],[1516629062,"1"],[1516629122,"1"],[1516629182,"1"],[1516629242,"1"],[1516629302,"1"],[1516629362,"1"],[1516629422,"1"],[1516629482,"1"],[1516629542,"1"],[1516629602,"1"],[1516629662,"1"],[1516629722,"1"],[1516629782,"1"],[1516629842,"1"],[1516629902,"1"],[1516629962,"1"],[1516630022,"1"],[1516630082,"1"],[1516630142,"1"],[1516630202,"1"],[1516630262,"1"],[1516630322,"1"],[1516630382,"1"],[1516630442,"1"],[1516630502,"1"],[1516630562,"1"],[1516630622,"1"],[1516630682,"1"],[1516630742,"1"],[1516630802,"1"],[1516630862,"1"],[1516630922,"1"],[1516630982,"1"],[1516631042,"1"],[1516631102,"1"],[1516631162,"1"],[1516631222,"1"],[1516631282,"1"],[1516631342,"1"],[1516631402,"1"],[1516631462,"1"]]}]}}
```

I want to GET values < 0.5 and name process_id satisfies the mask **fly**

```
http://server02/api/v1/query_range?query=count(process_status<0.5)&{process_id=~"*fly*"}&start=1516627862.0&end=1516631462.0&step=60
```

But result not good.
How make REST API request better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sum(process_status{process_id=~".*fly.*"} < bool 0.5)
```

Prometheus uses regular expressions, rather than globs. To handle the case where there are no matching series, you want to use the `bool` modifier which returns 0/1 and then sum it. Using `count` you would get a result of nothing (as distinct from 0) if no time series matched.

Answer (score 0):

Having the plain URL is a bit confusing. Especially with the unsecaped `&`. I suggest to test your queries via the web UI: http://server02/graph.

Your URL looks like you want to try something like `count(process_status<0.5)&{process_id=~"*fly*"}`, but because of the URL encoding it is actually `count(process_status<0.5)`.

The `=~` matcher uses regex. Therefore you have to write `process_id=~".*fly.*"` instead of just `*fly*`.

If I understood your question correctly, your query should look like this:

```
process_status{process_id=~".*fly.*"} < 0.5
```

Also the docs should be quite clear: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/